# Is there a way to manually redeliver message back to standard queue from dead letter? AWS SQS? ActiveMQ?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-camel, queue, activemq-classic, amazon-sqs

Need a way for an admin to place a message back for reprocessing after he reviewed it in dead letter queue. We are using both AWS SQS and Active MQ for different pieces of the system. Assume there was some connectivity problem that prevented the message from being processed that has been resolved.

Comment: Are you asking about both AWS SQS and ActiveMQ? Also, are you using ActiveMQ 5.x or Artemis? Please clarify.

Comment: We are using activemq 5.14.3 in one part of the system and SQS separately independently in another part of the system.

Comment: So which one has the message in the dead letter queue? That's what you're really asking about, right?

Comment: Both have dead letter queues. For both solutions, we need the same ability to be able to manually redeliver messages pack for reprocessing. You can help me to answer for one or for another. We may reconsider changing ActiveMQ pieces to SQS or vise versa. May leave both in place.

Comment: OK, so you're asking for two solutions in the same question. That's considered bad form on Stack Overflow. You need to focus your question to a single issue. Take a look at [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more details on improving your question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no command to send a message from an **Amazon SQS Dead Letter Queue** back to the original queue. In fact, there is no command to send messages between *any* queues.

Your application will need to send a new message to the queue, then delete the 'dead' message from the DLQ.